# Using url parameters in POST request

Tags: node.js, express, post

I am having some trouble using url parameters and `POST` data together in a single request.

I have a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="form-inline" _lpchecked="1">
    <label for="facetname">Add ethnicity</label>
    <input id="facetname" type="text" placeholder="ethnicity name" class="form-control"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is then posted to my `facet` route as follows:

```
router.post('/:facettype', FacetController.facet_create_post);
```

The FacetController then tries to access both the `facettype` and `facetname` elements of the `req.params` object but it includes only `facettype`:

```
exports.facet_create_post = (req,res,next) => {

    let facet_type = req.params.facettype;
    let name = req.params.facetname;

};
```

I've also tried `req.body` which is blank.

Have I missed something or does using a URL parameter remove the ability to use POST requests?

Comment: With a form that POSTs, the form data should be in req.body itself, ie req.body is the string `'facetname=namehere'`

Comment: @Li357 `req.body` is an empty object for me, although `req._body` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was mainly stupidity as I suspected.

I forgot the `name` parameter in the form input:

```
<input id="facetname" type="text" placeholder="ethnicity name" class="form-control">
```

Should have been:

```
<input id="facetname" name="facetname" type="text" placeholder="ethnicity name" class="form-control">
```